# How to redirect user to another view after saving the data using CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently working on a feature where when the user taps "save" button it redirects him to the view with the stack of flashcards created based on data user entered. I have tried to use the NavigationLink but it's been depreciated since IOS 16. Are there any other ways to implement this feature? Approach this NavigationLink doesn't work as when i ran an app and pressed "save" button i have got an error: Thread 1: "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."
Here's the code the view where the user enters the data and where the "save" button is located. :

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                  //  redirectToSet.toggle()
                    for testForm in viewModel.termdefpairs {
                        dataController.add(term: testForm.term, name: name, definition: testForm.definition, tag: testForm.tag, context: managedObjectContext)
                    }
                    isShowingSet = true
                    dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                })
                
                
                    NavigationLink(destination: SetView(), isActive: $isShowingSet) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
```

Here's newly applied approach, however, when doing so i receive a thread: executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

```
    NavigationStack { 
    List {
                     NavigationLink(destination: SetView(), isActive: $isShowingSet) {
                            EmptyView()
                            }
                  ForEach(viewModel.termdefpairs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
TermView(term: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].term, definition: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].definition, tag: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].tag)
                            
                            }
                            }
```

Comment: There is so much unnecessary code. Reduce your code to the minimum to reproduce your issue. It is unclear where you are trying to go and where your starting point is.

Comment: `NavigationLink` isn't deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

Comment: Navigation bar items isn’t located inside the NavigationView you have to trigger the NavigationLink with isActive by changing a Book instead. If you are supporting iOS 16+ I suggest changing to a navigationDestination setup to remove the warnings but if you are supporting versions below there isn’t much you can do. There is a whole migration guide on the Apple Developer site

Comment: how to change to the navigationDestination setup? the .navigationBar goes after the NavigationView

Comment: I have tried to use NavigationStack and put there NavigationLink. It works in the way that i'm redirected to the view, however, the data isn't fetching and i receive a thread: executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

Answer (score 0):

You can use toolbar instead of navigationBarItems - it will be deprecated also.

Working example -> https://i.imgur.com/ZMfhViB.mp4

This is what you need:

```
struct SomeYourView: View {
 @State private var isShowingSet = false

 var body: some View {
  NavigationStack {
   VStack {
    Button("Update detail") {
     isShowingSet = true
    }
   }
   .toolbar {
       ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { // 3
           Button {
               isShowingSet = true
           } label: {
               Text("Button")
           }
       }
   }
   .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isShowingSet) {
    VStack {
     Text("Deails was updated")
     Button("close") {
      isShowingSet = false
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```